# Response.Redirect does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-2007, response.redirect

I have a page that exports large amount of data to excel 2007 macro enabled format. I have Response.Redirect at the end to redirect to another page after the excel file is created but the redirect does not work when I have really large amount of data i.e about 60,000+ rows.
Below is the snippet of the code that I am using to save the excel file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=RegionData.xlsm");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
wbRegionData.Save(Response.OutputStream);//();
Response.End();
Response.Redirect("RegionData.aspx?PALID=" + AVListID, true);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you want to send a file download, and *then* redirect to another web page?  I'm not sure this is possible the way you're attempting it ...

Comment: It also looks like you are ending the response before the redirect?  That redirect line should never get called.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a file download and a redirect in the same server response. If you need to perform a redirect after a successful file download you will need to somehow tell the client that a file download successfully occurred which can only be accomplished by writing a cookie as far as I know.

I have created the jQuery File Download plugin ([Demo](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)) [(Blog Posts](http://johnculviner.com/category/jQuery-File-Download.aspx)) that simplifies a lot of this stuff, using the plugin your code could be like this:

ASP.NET CODE:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=RegionData.xlsm");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true"){Path = "/"});
wbRegionData.Save(Response.OutputStream);//();
Response.End();
```

JavaScript:

```
$.fileDownload("/urltofiledownload/", {
    successCallback: function (url) {
        window.location = "/redirecturl/";
    }
});
```

Without more of your code I can't give you a complete solution (look at the [Demo](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) for examples) but I think using the plugin would be your easiest and best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you are closing the response by calling [`Response.End();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) You must have to add define these two actions separately (Download and redirection).

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because the Respose.End() Method stop the normal execution of the page, I have refatored your code and delete de Response.End() Method, now it's work.

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=RegionData.xlsm");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    wbRegionData.Save(Response.OutputStream);//();
    Response.Redirect("RegionData.aspx?PALID=" + AVListID, true);
```

Comment: thank you all for your help, I did remove the response.end which redirected me to the other page, but my main concern is not redirecting to another page, its saving the excel file.I donot get the file save dialogue when I remove the response.redirect line.      
thank you all again.